# replacing mspaint.exe in windows xp

Tags: c#, windows, io, replace, paint

I created a custom paint program , it is really good and better than the Microsoft Paint , now i am on stage two of the program , where i want to replace the old mspaint.exe where located in C:\WINDOWS\system32\mspaint.exe with my custom paint application , i tried to do that by typing the command :

```
System.IO.File.Copy(@"mspaint.exe", "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\mspaint.exe", true);
```

And that was not successful , i just tried to make my custom application is the default paint program , but once i do that , the old mspaint keep comming back !!

EDIT : I am trying to do that in windows XP

EDIT 2 : i made a regestry key : LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\mspaint.exe and made a string value of name : debugger and added string : C:\windows\system32\mypaint.exe and whenever i try to open any image i get error message :

```
Unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application
```

and my custom program does not open.

Comment: Er... do you really want to start your paint program when the user goes to Start, Run, and types "mspaint", where the "ms" is short for MicroSoft? Or do you just want to open your paint program when the user double-clicks an image file?

Comment: There is no "default" paint program.  Just install yours and provide a way to change the file association for the right types (e.g. .bmp, etc.)  This is the wrong way to do it, but the security restrictions on the Windows folder won't let you do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can use [image file execution options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed%28vs.71%29.aspx) registry to forward calls of *mspaint.exe* to your exe.

In order to so:

1. Ceate a new registry key under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\currentversion\image file execution options`
2. Name it with `mspaint.exe`
3. Add a string value named `debugger` and set its value to your exe file

Comment: i tried that method , i created a key named mspaint.exe and inside it i created a string value : debugger with value : "%systemroot%\system32\mspaint1.exe" "%1" , but whenever i open an image for exmaple loacted in D:\ , i ger error : windows can not find file D:\image.png , Make sure you typed the name correctly and then try again.

Comment: @user1215216, I'm not sure you need to add "%1". I think the parameters sent to the original exe are passed to the new one (not sure but that's what I remember). If you just try to open mspaint does it launches your exe?

Comment: i removed the %1 but still it don`t open my exe

Comment: @user1215216, I tried it too and it seems that environment variables can't be used there. When I changed %systemroot% to c:\windows it started working.

Comment: Oh it worked , THANK YOU SO MUCH i changed it to C:\windows\system32\mypaint.exe

Comment: But there is a note : when i open any file related to paint i get error : Unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application